# Get Common Column value for multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT f1.FacNo, o1.CourseNo, f1.FacSupervisor 
from Faculty f1 
INNER JOIN Offering o1 on o1.FacNo = f1.FacNo AND o1.OffYear = 2017
```

[image]

is it possible to write a query which returns rows whose *FacNo* and *FacSupervisor* ***CourseNo*** are same?

I was hoping to do this without any loops or sorts.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Yes.  write query which gives a count of facno and supervisor having count() > 1 then join back to your base set.on the  facNo and facSupervisor.

Comment: this was my attempt. this is where I am stuck at. i think this dataset should suffice?

Comment: "i think this dataset should suffice" - the clearer you make your question the easier it is to answer.

Comment: "why the downvote" hover your mouse over the down arrow and it tells you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking, but this may get you close:

```
--original query
SELECT f1.FacNo, o1.CourseNo, f1.FacSupervisor 
FROM Faculty f1 
INNER JOIN Offering o1 on o1.FacNo = f1.FacNo AND o1.OffYear = 2017
 -- further narrow results for offerings with a supervisor matching the faculty member
INNER JOIN Offering o2 ON o2.FacNo = f1.FacSupervisor 
    -- for the same year and course
    AND o2.OffYear = o1.OffYear AND o2.CoursNo = o1.CourseNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Common table expression to get a count > 1 of each. then join back to base set.  I'll let you take care of the join back to offering...

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT FacNo, FacSupervisor
    FROM Faculty
    GROUP BY FacNo, FacSupervisor
    HAVING Count(*) > 1
)    
SELECT F.* 
FROM CTE C
INNER JOIN Faculty F
    ON F.FacNo = C.FacNo
    AND F.FacSupervisor = C.FacSupervisor
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested due to lack of DDL to create test data

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT  f1.FacNo, 
                    o1.CourseNo, 
                    f1.FacSupervisor,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f1.FacNo, o1.CourseNo, f1.FacSupervisor) AS RowN
            FROM    Faculty f1 
                    INNER JOIN Offering o1 
                        on o1.FacNo = f1.FacNo AND o1.OffYear = 2017
        ) a
WHERE RowN > 1
```